# Informatica skipped records need to be written to bad files

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

in my case, i have an expression transformation which uses the default function ERROR('transformation') to skip the records in which date value coming inside is not in the correct format. In this, the skipped rows are not written to the reject files, so that we are getting the reconcilation problem. I need the skipped rows to be written to the bad files.Please help me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `Update Strategy` transformation in your mapping and flag these rows for reject (use the `DD_REJECT` constant).

More information: [Update Strategy Transformation](http://informaticatutorials-naveen.blogspot.com/2011/04/update-strategy-transformation.html)

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks. but i dont need to change my setup. i need any functional changes within to handle this.IIF(EndDate = '', NULL, to_date(EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')).This is the expression we are using. Actually, i had a doubt, if i dint use that default value, and if any invalid row comes, whether that session gets failed.

Comment: Here's a description of the `ERROR` function: *Causes the PowerCenter Integration Service to skip a row and issue an error message, which you define. The error message displays in the session log. The PowerCenter Integration Service does not write these skipped rows to the session reject file.* So you cannot use `ERROR` to make PowerCenter reject rows - you need to flag them as `DD_REJECT` or the target database needs to reject them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't use the abort() function then. Use a router to write the bad formated dates to a different target then.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now i have some other problem, where there are two expression transformations,in which both has the date transformation like IIF(EndDate = '', NULL, to_date(EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')).The records should pass through both the transformations so that which causes the error. But in the session log the error message is like as folows   error transforming (s:'10/09/2013', s:YYYY-MM-DD) I need to know,from where this mm/dd/yyyy format comes. note:(My source is a flat file)

Comment: I don't see the problem. Move the check for the badly formated date as early as possible and flag those rows as errors using the mentioned `Update Strategy` or using a `Router` transformation.